# How to enforce values in a map in Firestore rules without knowing the keys?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement something similar to ["Working with Arrays, Lists, and Sets" example in Firestore's document,](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays) but for user access control list.

In a document, there'll be a `modified` field of a timestamp, and a `users` field of a map, containing user's UID as a key and the modified timestamp as value (so that I can sort using this field).

```
{
    modified: 2018-01-01T17:05:00Z,
    users: {
        someUID: 2018-01-01T17:05:00Z,
        otherUID: 2018-01-01T17:05:00Z
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

It's obvious that I have to keep the values inside `users` map in sync with the `modified` field. As I don't want to pay a cloud function call and a document write whenever the document is updated, I plan to do the update on the client, at the same time the document itself is updated.

The question is, how can I enforce, using Firestore security rules, the values of `users` map so that it'll always be in sync with the modified field? The keys of this map isn't known in advance, and the size of this map can be variable, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `writeFields` for update rules if `map` is variable or keys are unknown while updating.

```
allow update: if request.auth != null
     && request.resource.data.users is map
     && request.writeFields.size() == 1
     && (('users.' + request.auth.uid) in request.writeFields)
     && request.resource.data.users[request.auth.uid] <= request.time.time();
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for. Your example can only enforce the timestamp of the updater and not everyone else. I want it to apply to every field in the map.